# Replacing certain lines in a statemement

Tags: oracle, plsql, regexp-replace

I am exporting ddl statemements for tables using dbms_metadata.set_transform_param package. This works as intended. However, I am also interested to remove a certain lines from the output.

For example: here is the output of one of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "FREEZES" 
   (    "PLAYER_ID" NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PRODUCT_ID" NUMBER(19,0)
   )   
  TABLESPACE "MINE" ;
  ALTER TABLE "FREEZES" ADD CONSTRAINT "FREEZES_U" UNIQUE ("PLAYER_ID", "PRODUCT_ID")
  USING INDEX   
  TABLESPACE "MINE_IDX"  ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "FREEZES" ADD SUPPLEMENTAL LOG DATA (PRIMARY KEY) COLUMNS;
  ALTER TABLE "FREEZES" ADD SUPPLEMENTAL LOG DATA (FOREIGN KEY) COLUMNS;
  ALTER TABLE "FREEZES" ADD SUPPLEMENTAL LOG DATA (UNIQUE INDEX) COLUMNS;
  ALTER TABLE "FREEZES" ADD SUPPLEMENTAL LOG DATA (ALL) COLUMNS;
```

What I would like to have is:

```
CREATE TABLE "FREEZES" 
   (    "PLAYER_ID" NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PRODUCT_ID" NUMBER(19,0)
   )   
  TABLESPACE "MINE" ;
  ALTER TABLE "FREEZES" ADD CONSTRAINT "FREEZES_U" UNIQUE ("PLAYER_ID", "PRODUCT_ID")
  USING INDEX   
  TABLESPACE "MINE_IDX"  ENABLE;
```

And here is the query I am using:

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl(object_type, object_name, owner) as object_ddl
from dba_objects where owner = 'MINE' and object_type = 'TABLE';
```

I do know that I have to use regular expressions, something like:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(dbms_metadata.get_ddl(object_type, object_name, owner), 'pattren') as object_ddl
    from dba_objects where owner = 'MINE' and object_type = 'TABLE';
```

Comment: You could try if that can be excluded by calling `set_transform_param()` before calling `get_ddl()`: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#BGBJBFGE

Comment: yes, using   dbms_metadata.set_transform_param( dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', false); works but this also takes out tablespace information as well

Comment: You have to be able to specify very precisely what you want removed. For example, it can't be "any substring that begins with ALTER TABLE and ends with a semicolon" - that would take out the unique constraint as well. Perhaps everything after the TABLESPACE ENABLE statement? You need to be 100% sure that your specification will not result in deleting things you don't want deleted.